# Regex with multiple character separator

Tags: c++, regex

I have this string

```
options{Red | Blue | Green}
```

And I want to capture the options inside the curly braces one by one. So far I was able to capture the inner part, but I don't understand how to set the pattern SPACELINESPACE `|` as a separator and capture Red Blue and Green.

For capturing the string inside the curly braces I used this
`options{(.)*}`

I had some results in capturing the values serapately with this:

```
(.+?)(?: \| |$)
```

But when I compose everything like this `options={(.+?)(?: \| |$)}` I do not capture anything

Comment: What tool / programming language are you using?

Comment: @sindri_baldur C++14 regex, testing everything with regex101

Comment: Use `options\{(.*?)\}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, no, this does not add anything to what I have now. I need to capture Red Blue and Green separated, in three different capture groups. I will improve the question

Comment: Can you use boost? `(?:\w+{|\G(?!^))(?: \| )?\K\w+` https://regex101.com/r/BfBOYt/1

Comment: @JvdV I am not sure if the OP can use the engine that supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use something like:

```
\w+(?=[^{]*?})
```

---

**EDIT 1:** OP mentioned in the comment below:

> *"what if I have something like this, `options{Red | Blue | green },users={ Paul | Ringo | John | George}`? I want to capture just the options."*

I'm unsure what flavor is used, but the below pattern will negate the substrings that are found in 'users'.

```
\busers={.*?}(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+(?=[^{]*?})
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8d8DDt/6)

---

**EDIT 2:**

Without knowing if there are more categories other than 'users' that need to be negated, we could extend the pattern above:

```
(?<!\boptions){.*?}(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+(?=[^{]*?})
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8d8DDt/10)

Another way would be to use boost and match substrings using:

```
(?:\boptions{|\G(?!^))(?:[ |]+)?\K\w+
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8d8DDt/8)

Comment: This works with the proposed string. Can you please explain it a little bit more? Also, what if I have something like this, `options{Red | Blue | green },users={ Paul | Ringo | John | George}`? I want to capture just the options.

Comment: @JvdV Unless specified in the question, c++ tag implies the ECMAScript 5 flavor.

Comment: C++ is cool since it allows installing and using many other flavors, like PCRE2, PCRE, Boost, ICU. So, it might still be valid :)

Comment: Thanks for thinking along @WiktorStribiżew and specifying this about c++ (which I don't know nothing about). Hopefully the answer is now usefull to OP.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the rest in several (non regex) steps :
Use your first regex, split on `|`, and trim.

If you want to do all of it in regex and end up with each color in a different group, it might be more complicated but doable, I'll try for the challenge.
Are there always 3 colors ? If so, it's much easier.

EDIT :
With only regex, this will do the trick `(?!.*\{)([^ |}]+)`, with the options in group 1

https://regex101.com/r/0Zjzz8/1

Comment: No, the options may be more than one